# polynomial equation parameters

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have some 2D sampling points for which I need the polynomial equation. I only found something like this:

```
from scipy.interpolate import barycentric_interpolate
// x and y are given as lists
yi = barycentric_interpolate(x, y, xi)
```

But in this case I can only get the y-values belonging to certain xi-values - that's not what I want. I need the equation (the parameter for the polynomial equation). How can I receive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[numpy.polyfit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)

> Fit a polynomial p(x) = p[0] * x**deg + ... + p[deg] of degree deg to
>   points (x, y). Returns a vector of coefficients p that minimises the
>   squared error.

Example from the docs:

```
>>> x = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0,  4.0,  5.0])
>>> y = np.array([0.0, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1, -0.8, -1.0])
>>> z = np.polyfit(x, y, 3)
>>> z
array([ 0.08703704, -0.81349206,  1.69312169, -0.03968254])
```

Comment: thank you, that's exactly what I've been looking for!

Answer (score -1):

with [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html?highlight=curve_fit#scipy.optimize.curve_fit) one can fit arbitrary functions and obtain its coefficients