# numpy.polyfit with adapted parameters

Tags: python, numpy, polynomial-math

Regarding to this: [polynomial equation parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21973740/polynomial-equation-parameters) 
where I get 3 parameters for a squared function `y = a*x² + b*x + c` now I want only to get the **first** parameter for a squared function which describes my function `y = a*x²`. With other words: I want to set `b=c=0` and get the adapted parameter for `a`. In case I understand it right, polyfit isn't able to do this.

Comment: `np.polyfit` is used to fit a polynomial to some points, how do you know your `y = a*x²` would fit your points?

Comment: I can guarantee that my points fit y=a*x²... when I use polyfit I get some values <10^(-2) for b and c. (while a>20)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done by [numpy.linalg.lstsq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html). To explain how to use it, it is maybe easiest to show how you would do a standard 2nd order polyfit 'by hand'. Assuming you have your measurement vectors `x` and `y`, you first construct a so-called [design matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_matrix) `M` like so:

```
M = np.column_stack((x**2, x, np.ones_like(x)))
```

after which you can obtain the usual coefficients as the least-square solution to the equation `M * k = y` using `lstsq` like this:

```
k, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(M, y)
```

where `k` is the column vector `[a, b, c]` with the usual coefficients. Note that `lstsq` returns some other parameters, which you can ignore. This is a very powerful trick, which allows you to fit `y` to any linear combination of the columns you put into your design matrix. It can be used e.g. for 2D fits of the type `z = a * x + b * y` (see e.g. [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18552769/2647279), where I used the same trick in Matlab), or polyfits with missing coefficients like in your problem.

In your case, the design matrix is simply a single column containing `x**2`. Quick example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

# generate some noisy data
x = np.arange(1000)
y = 0.0001234 * x**2 + 3*np.random.randn(len(x))

# do fit
M = np.column_stack((x**2,)) # construct design matrix
k, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(M, y) # least-square fit of M * k = y

# quick plot
plt.plot(x, y, '.', x, k*x**2, 'r', linewidth=3)
plt.legend(('measurement', 'fit'), loc=2)
plt.title('best fit: y = {:.8f} * x**2'.format(k[0]))
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

The coefficients are get to minimize the squared error, you don't assign them. However, you can set some of the coefficients to zero if they are too much insignificant. E.g., I have a list of points on curve `y = 33*x²`:

```
In [51]: x=np.arange(20)

In [52]: y=33*x**2  #y = 33*x²

In [53]: coeffs=np.polyfit(x, y, 2)

In [54]: coeffs
Out[54]: array([  3.30000000e+01,   8.99625199e-14,  -7.62430619e-13])

In [55]: epsilon=np.finfo(np.float32).eps

In [56]: coeffs[np.abs(coeffs)<epsilon]=0

In [57]: coeffs
Out[57]: array([ 33.,   0.,   0.])
```

Comment: This would only work for noise-less data. In case your data contains noise, also the other coefficients will be non-zero, and your estimate for your quadratic term will not contain the optimal value.