# Fitting Data to a Square-root or Logarithmic Function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, regression, square-root

So I have some data:

```
ensub = np.array([0, 10, 12, 14, 13.5, 12.3, 14, 13.1, 13, 12.9, 14, 14, 13, 13])
time = np.array([0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39])
```

and I plot it, I'd like to find a fit. So the natural course of action to take it a `poly1d` of some sort:

```
enfit = np.polyfit(time, ensub, 2)
ene = np.poly1d(enfit)
xen = np.linspace(time[0], time[-1], 100)
yen = ene(xen)
plt.plot(time,ensub,'o', xen, yen, color='blue')
```

which produces following plot:
[image: Plot1]

I get something like this, which is fine usually. But I know that this data would fit really well to a different function, like a [square-root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root) or [logarithmic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm).

This kind of graph would be preffered:
[image: BetterPlot]

How can I fit a more accurate equation to this data, show it, and have it be callable?

Comment: Look up 'nonlinear regression'.  I believe scipy has a function to do it.

Comment: you can construct your own x_new = (x, x**2, log(x), exp(x)) etc. and then fit a multi var linear regression for (y, x_new). See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126229/numpy-polyfit-with-adapted-parameters) for how to do a multi var fit.